# requests.get(url).json(): JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I tried to use requests' json() but got the error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). My code as below:

```
################
import requests
url='https://www.google.com'
response= requests.get(url) 
print(response) 
print(response.content) 
r=response.json()
################
```

I've looked at threads on this issue but their solutions haven't helped resolve the error.

```
<Response [200]>
text/html;charset=UTF-8
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n \r\n\r\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:tcdl="http://www.tridion.com/ContentDelivery/5.3/TCDL"  class="no-js" lang="en">\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<head>\r\n    \r\n    <script nonce="de7946e9-7383-4cf6-9793-8cbe62df2d65">\r\n        document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace(/(^|\\s)no-js(\\s|$)/, \'$1$2\');\r\n    </script>\r\n  
...
</script> \n\r\n\r\n\r\n</body>\r\n</html>'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c7a16189e451> in <module>
     7 print(response.headers.get('Content-Type'))
     8 print(response.content)
----> 9 r=response.json()
    10 # Making a GET request ,headers={'content-type':'application/json'}
    11 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
   896                     # used.
   897                     pass
--> 898         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
   899 
   900     @property

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
   346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
   347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
   349     if cls is None:
   350         cls = JSONDecoder

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
   335 
   336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
   338         end = _w(s, end).end()
   339         if end != len(s):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
   353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
   354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
   356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Thus far it looks request.get(url) returns good info. ,but response.json() has come up with the error.
I tried forcing the encoding as r=resp.json(encoding='utf-8-sig') but did not help, got same error.

I also uninstalled simplejson and upgraded the requests module, still same error.
I am using Python 3.7.1 Anaconda3(64bit), the requests module version is 2.24.0

Comment: The `print` results at the top clearly show that you received an HTML document, not json data. It's unclear what you're expecting the `response.json()` result to look like.

Answer (score 2):

Hi the website you are trying parse using GET request is google.com which is a html document.
When you do `response.json()`, it is trying to convert the html document into a json object, however because response is not of json format, you will get JSON decode error!

Hopefully that helps